# How to wrap cell text

Tags: tables, text, wrap

Could someone help me wrap the text in the first line of this table, it keeps exceeding the line width of the page and the `\\` command doesn't work. Mainly the end three columns first row.

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X | X | X | X}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Photoresist}}}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Soft Bake Time at 95 \textdegree C}}}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Exposure Energy (mJ/cm\textsuperscript{2})}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Post Exposure Bake Time at 95 \textdegree C}}}\tabularnewline \hline
        
    SU-8 2000.5  & 1760 & 1.5 & 0.4 \\ \hline
    SU-8 2002     & 1190 & 3.2 & 0.35 \\ 
    
    \end{tabularx}
    
\caption[Parameter properties for PVC and acrylic.]{Parameter properties for PVC and acrylic.}
\label{Parameter properties}   
\end{table}
```

Comment: The `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` wrappers override the `c` column type.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap text manually or auto.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Parameter properties for PVC and acrylic.}
\label{Parameter properties}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec    = {*{4}{X[-1,c,m]}},
row{1}     = {font=\bfseries\itshape},
hline{1,Z} = {wd=.08em},
hline{2}   = {wd=.05em},
}
Photoresist & {Soft Bake\\Time at\\95 \textdegree C} & {Exposure\\Energy\\(mJ/cm\textsuperscript{2})} & {Post Exposure\\Bake Time at\\95 \textdegree C}\\
SU-8 2000.5 & 1760 & 1.5 & 0.4 \\
SU-8 2002 & 1190 & 3.2 & 0.35 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Parameter properties for PVC and acrylic.}
\label{Parameter properties}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec    = {*{4}{X[-1,c,m]}},
row{1}     = {font=\bfseries\itshape},
hline{1,Z} = {wd=.08em},
hline{2}   = {wd=.05em},
}
Photoresist & Soft Bake Time at 95 \textdegree C & Exposure Energy (mJ/cm\textsuperscript{2}) & Post Exposure Bake Time at 95 \textdegree C\\
SU-8 2000.5 & 1760 & 1.5 & 0.4 \\
SU-8 2002 & 1190 & 3.2 & 0.35 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A small variation od @Clara answer (+1): introduced is use of the`siunitx` package:

```
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}   % <---
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}  % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Parameter properties for PVC and acrylic.}
\label{Parameter properties}
\begin{tblr}{colspec    = {l    X[c]                          % <---
                           *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},% <---
             row{1}     = {guard, font=\bfseries\itshape, m}, % <---
             hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2}=solid,
            }
Photoresist &   {Soft Bake\\ Time at\\ \qty{95}{\celsius}}
                        &   Exposure Energy \normalfont(\unit{\milli\joule\per\square\cm})
                                    &   Post Exposure Bake Time at \qty{95}{\celsius}    \\
SU-8 2000.5 & 1760      & 1.5       & 0.4       \\
SU-8 2002   & 1190      & 3.2       & 0.35      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X | X | X | X}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{Y|}{\textit{\textbf{Photoresist}}}      & \multicolumn{1}{Y|}{\textit{\textbf{Soft Bake Time at 95 \textdegree C}}}        & \multicolumn{1}{Y|}{\textit{\textbf{Exposure Energy (mJ/cm\textsuperscript{2})}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{\textit{\textbf{Post Exposure Bake Time at 95 \textdegree C}}}\tabularnewline \hline
        
    SU-8 2000.5  & 1760 & 1.5 & 0.4 \\ \hline
    SU-8 2002     & 1190 & 3.2 & 0.35 \\ 
    
    \end{tabularx}
    
\caption[Parameter properties for PVC and acrylic.]{Parameter properties for PVC and acrylic.}
\label{Parameter properties}   
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostic: Unnecessary and harmful use of multi columns, that with the `c` style prevent wrapping text.

On the other hand, because the unequal headers and contents, it will look better with unequal columns using `tabulary`, where moreover is just easier set centered columns. BTW, it also will look better with `booktabs` (also without bold font, imho, with as this will change the constrains of the MWE, here you are with bold headers):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary, booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{cCCC}\toprule
\bfseries\em Photoresist                        & 
\bfseries\em Soft Bake Time at 95\,°C           & 
\bfseries\em  Exposure Energy (mJ/cm²)          &
\bfseries\em  Post Exposure Bake Time at 95\,°C  \\\midrule
    SU-8 2000.5  & 1760 & 1.5 & 0.4 \\ 
    SU-8 2002     & 1190 & 3.2 & 0.35 \\\bottomrule 
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks great!